# It is possible to use a LGPL module on a Electron app licensed as Apache 2.0?

Tags: licensing, open-source, node.js, lgpl, apache-license

I'm developing a desktop app (using Node.js and Electron), licensing the code under *Apache License v2.0*

**It's possible to add a module, licensed as *Lesser GPL v3*, to my app?**

I know that *compiled* LGPL libraries can be used on any type of projects (including commercial projects), as long as the linking is dynamic.

Does this also apply to libraries developed in interpreted languages (such as JavaScript) which can't be compiled?

Does this answer changes if I package my application using a tool like [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-packager)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use Apache Software License, Version 2.0 and GNU LGPL 3 licence plugins in my commercial web application?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/227639/can-i-use-apache-software-license-version-2-0-and-gnu-lgpl-3-licence-plugins-in)